Dense subspaces of relative commutants
Suppose $A \subseteq B \subseteq B(H)$ be an unital inclusion of C*-algebras. Let $\left\{ S_\lambda \right\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a disjoint family of subspaces of $B$ satisfying the following :

$S_\lambda \cap A'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ for each $\lambda \in \Lambda $.
$B = \overline{\text{span}} \left\{ \sqcup S_\lambda\right\}$, where the closure is in norm.

Is $B \cap A'$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ ?
If needed, one can additionally assume that $A \cap A' \simeq \mathbb{C}$ and there is a conditional expectation $E : B \to A$.
Any insight or suggestion will be really helpful.
($A'$ denotes the commutant of $A$ in $B(H)$ )

By “isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$”, do you just mean isomorphic as vector spaces (i.e., the spaces involved are one-dimensional)? (Since $S_\lambda$ are just assumed to be subspaces.)

(And by “disjoint” family of subspaces, I assume you meant the pairwise intersection is trivial, i.e., $S_\lambda \cap S_\mu = {0}$ for all $\lambda \neq \mu$?)

@DavidGao yes for both the questions

Well, then $A = \mathbb{C}$, $B = B(H)$, and ${S_\lambda}$ being the collection of one-dimensional subspaces of $B(H)$ is a counterexample. (And it even satisfies your two additional assumptions.)
